# Could burning Jagera (Foambark) create an allergic reaction?

Tags: wild-camping

Could burning [Jagera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagera_pseudorhus) (Foambark) create an allergic reaction? i.e. swollen throat, feet, hands, eyes, breathing trouble and aching body?

Answer (score 3):

Foambark can cause [contact dermatitis](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/000869.htm) and is listed by [aboutthegarden](http://www.aboutthegarden.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/ATG-Fact-Sheet-23-Low-allergy-gardens.pdf?38192e) as one of many low-allergen to avoid in an allergen free garden.